# Dynamic memory allocation - 2 dimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, dynamic

I have some troubles understanding pointers and dynamic memory allocation. I wrote those 2 codes:

```
    int **array;
    array = malloc(nrows * sizeof(int *));
    if(array == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
        return -1;
    }
        for(i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
    {
        *(array+i) = malloc(ncolumns * sizeof(int));
        if(array[i] == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

and:

```
    int **array;
    array = malloc(nrows * sizeof(int *));
    if(array == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
        return -1;
    }
        for(i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
    {
        array[i] = malloc(ncolumns * sizeof(int));
        if(array[i] == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

They should allocate space for 2 dimensional array. Although Im not sure if theyre both correct, I mean: does this line:

`array[i] = malloc(ncolumns * sizeof(int));`

do the exact same thing line this one:

`*(array+i) = malloc(ncolumns * sizeof(int));`

?

Comment: That is a lot of malloc'ing.  Why not 1 malloc for the entire dataset to just int *array?   array=malloc(nrows*ncolumnc*sizeof()), reference by array[x*nrows+y] or array[x+ncolumns*y].  Your last question is correct they are the same, though the first line is cleaner looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `*(array + i)` and `array[i]` evaluate to the same thing (assuming that one is a pointer and the other an integer).  For your sanity and everyone else's, use the second form; it'll be easier to read and maintain.

If you know the size of your array dimensions at compile time, or if you are working with a compiler that supports *variable-length arrays*, you can simplify this a bit:

```
int (*array)[ncols] = malloc( sizeof *array * nrows );
```

This will allocate enough memory for an `nrows` x `ncols` array of `int`.  If you're working with a compiler that does not support variable-length arrays, then `ncols` must be known at compile time (i.e., it must be a macro or other compile-time constant).  You would access array elements as you would for any regular 2D array:

```
array[i][j] = x;
```

One advantage this method has over the two-step method is that all the memory is allocated *contiguously*; that is, all the rows will be adjacent in memory.  This can matter if you want to treat the array as a single continuous blob of data (such as if you're sending it over a socket via a `write` system call).  With the two-step method, it's not guaranteed that all the rows will be adjacent.

The other advantage is that deallocation only requires a single call to `free`:

```
free( array );
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

`array[i]`, `*(array+i)` and `i[array]` are treated as same things by the compiler.

Comment: `i[array]` ? Are you sure?

Comment: Yes. Try it yourself.

Comment: @egur `array[i]` and `i[array]` are the same.  If you rewrite them you'll see they are the same as `*(array + i)` and `*(i + array)`, respectively.

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay +1 from me too. Nice to learn new things. Maybe not so good for a new programmer to write code like this though :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they should all be treated the same when you compile your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
int **array;
array = malloc(nrows * sizeof(int *));
```

the variable array is an array of pointer or double pointer variable. the value of these  pointers are done in the next array allocation :

```
array[i] = malloc(ncolumns * sizeof(int)); or 
*(array+i) = malloc(ncolumns * sizeof(int));
```

`array [i]`==> i is the index of array witch contain the value of pointer allocated by `malloc(ncolumns * sizeof(int));`

`*(array + i)` ==> is the offset using to parse array and *array + i) is the value of pointer allocated by `malloc(ncolumns * sizeof(int));`

so

```
array[i] = malloc(ncolumns * sizeof(int));
and 
*(array+i) = malloc(ncolumns * sizeof(int));
```

are exactly the same